# Copy PySpark Dataframe to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark

I am trying to load a dataframe created with PySpark in DataBricks to MySql but it tells me:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

```py
df_videojuegos.select("Nombre", "Plataforma", "Año", "Genero", "Editorial", "Ventas NA", "Ventas EU", "Ventas JP", "Ventas Otros", "Ventas Global") \
    .write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dezyre_db&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false") \
    .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "reportes") \
    .option("user", "root").option("password", "root") \
    .save()
```

I already have the connector installed in the cluster for MySql and these imported libraries:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config("spark.jars", "/home/hduser/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar") \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("PySpark_MySQL_test2") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

I don't know if the url that I have declared is really correct, or if I have the syntax wrong.

Install the connectors, create the connection with MySQL but when loading the data it gives me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the error was a newbie, I was trying to connect from DataBricks to a localhost! :C

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).